# Google form response not appearing in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have around 120 different values to be shown in drop down in a Google form. Given this long list, instead of typing manually, with the help of App Script I have filled the list of values to be shown to the user in the drop down list on that Google form. This form has some other questions also.

After running the script, I can see the all those values do reflect the drop down in the  Google form and also on the live form.

When the user fills the Google form and submits, all the responses are appearing in the sheet attached to Google form except  the value chosen by the user in that drop down which has the list of values filled programmatically.

```
function FillDropDown(){
  var form = FormApp.openById("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"); 
  var HouseAddressList = form.getItemById("987145236").asListItem();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Form data");

  var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 2, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var HouseAddressAddress = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)   
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      HouseAddressAddress[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  HouseAddressList.setChoiceValues(HouseAddressAddress);
}
```

The script used to fill drop down is given above.

Any pointers on what might be causing this.

Comment: I would suggest you post the script that fills in the values for the dropdown.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, I have updated the question with the script.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your situation.  I created a simple form and populated a dropdown with several choices exactly as you have done.  I email to myself and choose an option from the dropdown.  In the spreadsheet linked to the form I see only the choice I made.  Repeated the form and again only the choice I made shows up in the newest row of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Further to this, I noticed that the values from the drop down are coming in the response sheet but for some reason the response sheet has a new column at the end to reflect response submitted by the user for that drop down, There was already a column in the middle but that is being skipped. Not sure why?

Comment: Since the column in response sheet originally meant to store the response for Google form drop down was left blank, it gave an impression that values are not being captured, but in reality the value was getting stored as last column in response sheet skipping the column in the middle which was meant to be used, Still struggling to understand the cause of that.

Comment: An alternative to using a script is to copy the 120 dropdown options i.e. from Google Sheets and paste them at once directly in the Google Form editor.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. If you try to reproduce it with another form, does the same error occur? Perhaps the Google Sheets attached to the form was modified in some way before running the script?